# Upper bound on edge set size of graph that has lower bound on cycle length

Tags: graph-theory

For a graph with $n$ nodes, if the shortest cycle in the graph has at most $2t-1$ edges for $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the graph has at most $\mathcal{O}(n^{1+1/t})$ edges.

Is this claim or some close variant of this claim true? It is used in this paper [https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mcgregor/papers/13-graphsurvey.pdf](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Emcgregor/papers/13-graphsurvey.pdf) but I haven't been able to find the proof in the cited source.

If it is true, I'm curious to see the proof. If what I have typed is slightly off, then perhaps someone can direct me to the correct statement of the claim and its proof.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be true.

The length of the shortest cycle in a graph is called the graph's **[girth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_(graph_theory))**. The claim is a bound on the number of edges in graphs with high (odd) girth.

I found this 2002 PhD thesis, entitled [On Graphs of High Girth](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.142.5153&rep=rep1&type=pdf). On page 23 of this thesis, the author asks:

> What is the maximal number of edges in a graph with $n$ vertices and girth $g$?

Theorem 1 of that section provides, with a detailed complex proof, the following bound when $g$ takes the form $2r-1$:

$$ n \geq 1 + d \sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(d-1)^i,$$

where $d$ represents the average degree of the graph. If we let $m$ be the number of edges in the graph, we may write $d = n/m$, and rewrite the above inequality in terms of $n$ and $m$. The required $m = O(n^{1+1/t})$ emerges after replacing the geometric sum with the formula $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x^i = (1-x^k)/(1-x)$ and after performing some basic algebra.